# Как  пятиклассникам  объясняют  грамматику?

Tags: грамматика, методика

В книге  «Сборник сочинений для 5-9 классов» встретился такой текст:

«Про белку и говорить нечего. Где тяжелый орешек подберет, где плотный грибочек раздобудет – всё в свои владения тащит».

Предложение  разговорного стиля, семантика несложная, знаки препинания очевидные, но как в пятом  классе, да и в других классах тоже,  объясняют такую   грамматику и пунктуацию?

ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ВОПРОС

Уважаемые филологи и лингвисты, помогите, пожалуйста,  определить грамматическую форму этого нестандартного предложения.

Answer (score 3):

А где это Вы такую учебную книгу («Сборник сочинений для 5-9 классов») нашли? Очередные шпаргалки, подсказки - макулатура, одним словом. Таких предложений в настоящих учебных пособиях для 5-х классов нет, никто им и не даёт объяснений по поводу такого синтаксиса и пунктуации. Вот в изложениях для 8-9 кл. могут встретиться, но там уже изучают неполные предложения с пропуском подлежащего, ничего страшного в их грамматике нет, а пунктуация, если встречается,в диктантах например, подсказывается учителем, такое возможно при встрече с трудными случаями. Если же это в 10-11 классах, то они знают об интонационном тире, когда простое предложение распадается на две группы, чтобы уточнить смысловые отношения. Если учитель правильно прочитает, они этот смысл улавливают легко: первые части связаны интонацией перечисления - ставим запятую, третья часть отделена паузой, отделяющей часть, где имеется обобщение ВСЁ - ставим тире.

Comment: В принципе не так важно, откуда взят текст, хотя на книге указано "по новому образовательному стандарту". Ничего плохого, вредного и  и макулатурного я в таких пособиях не вижу - даны образцы сочинений (эссе, рассуждение, повествование, диалог) для разных классов. Никто не предлагает их списывать, просто удобно ознакомиться с различными формами сочинений, прежде чем написать собственное. Что касается структуры предложения, то оно типично для подобных описаний и  часто встречается. Но все-таки интересно, могут ли школьники определить его грамматику, или им доступно только интонационное решение

Comment: Не знаю, как в 5-6 классах , а в для 9-10 классов здесь нет никакой трудности. Я мало знаком со школьной программой, но знаю, что, например, в 5-6 классах уже изучают тропы, фигуры речи( и достаточно сложные). По сравнению с этим, такие предложения не представляют трудности для 5-6 классов( на мой взгляд).

Comment: Серж, а как Вы определяете вид этого предложения (или фигуры речи)?